Parsing error thrown when loading recipe (fabric)
I am writing a simple mod to add a few items that play sounds when you use them. I'm workingon the crafting recipe and I know I have everything spelled right. I'm getting an exception when I load my testing world.
[11:50:17] [Render thread/ERROR] (Minecraft) Parsing error loading recipe ingamesoundboard:uwu_sound_recipe
 com.google.gson.JsonParseException: No key id in MapLike[{"item":"ingamesoundboard:uwu_sound"}]
    at com.mojang.serialization.DataResult$Error.getOrThrow(DataResult.java:275) ~[datafixerupper-7.0.14.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.recipe.RecipeManager.apply(RecipeManager.java:62) ~[minecraft-common-8cf9c5407c-1.20.5-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_20_5.1.20.5+build.1-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.recipe.RecipeManager.apply(RecipeManager.java:35) ~[minecraft-common-8cf9c5407c-1.20.5-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_20_5.1.20.5+build.1-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.resource.SinglePreparationResourceReloader.method_18790(SinglePreparationResourceReloader.java:13) ~[minecraft-common-8cf9c5407c-1.20.5-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_20_5.1.20.5+build.1-v2.jar:?]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniAccept.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:718) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:482) ~[?:?]
    at net.minecraft.resource.SimpleResourceReload.method_18365(SimpleResourceReload.java:69) ~[minecraft-common-8cf9c5407c-1.20.5-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_20_5.1.20.5+build.1-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.util.thread.ThreadExecutor.executeTask(ThreadExecutor.java:162) ~[minecraft-common-8cf9c5407c-1.20.5-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_20_5.1.20.5+build.1-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.util.thread.ReentrantThreadExecutor.executeTask(ReentrantThreadExecutor.java:23) ~[minecraft-common-8cf9c5407c-1.20.5-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_20_5.1.20.5+build.1-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.util.thread.ThreadExecutor.runTask(ThreadExecutor.java:136) ~[minecraft-common-8cf9c5407c-1.20.5-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_20_5.1.20.5+build.1-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.util.thread.ThreadExecutor.runTasks(ThreadExecutor.java:145) ~[minecraft-common-8cf9c5407c-1.20.5-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_20_5.1.20.5+build.1-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.server.integrated.IntegratedServerLoader.load(IntegratedServerLoader.java:182) ~[minecraft-clientOnly-8cf9c5407c-1.20.5-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_20_5.1.20.5+build.1-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.server.integrated.IntegratedServerLoader.load(IntegratedServerLoader.java:137) ~[minecraft-clientOnly-8cf9c5407c-1.20.5-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_20_5.1.20.5+build.1-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.server.integrated.IntegratedServerLoader.start(IntegratedServerLoader.java:323) ~[minecraft-clientOnly-8cf9c5407c-1.20.5-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_20_5.1.20.5+build.1-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.server.integrated.IntegratedServerLoader.start(IntegratedServerLoader.java:313) ~[minecraft-clientOnly-8cf9c5407c-1.20.5-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_20_5.1.20.5+build.1-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.server.integrated.IntegratedServerLoader.start(IntegratedServerLoader.java:278) ~[minecraft-clientOnly-8cf9c5407c-1.20.5-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_20_5.1.20.5+build.1-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.server.integrated.IntegratedServerLoader.start(IntegratedServerLoader.java:243) ~[minecraft-clientOnly-8cf9c5407c-1.20.5-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_20_5.1.20.5+build.1-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.screen.world.WorldListWidget$WorldEntry.play(WorldListWidget.java:434) ~[minecraft-clientOnly-8cf9c5407c-1.20.5-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_20_5.1.20.5+build.1-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.screen.world.WorldListWidget$WorldEntry.mouseClicked(WorldListWidget.java:411) ~[minecraft-clientOnly-8cf9c5407c-1.20.5-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_20_5.1.20.5+build.1-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.widget.EntryListWidget.mouseClicked(EntryListWidget.java:306) ~[minecraft-clientOnly-8cf9c5407c-1.20.5-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_20_5.1.20.5+build.1-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.ParentElement.mouseClicked(ParentElement.java:38) ~[minecraft-clientOnly-8cf9c5407c-1.20.5-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_20_5.1.20.5+build.1-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Mouse.method_1611(Mouse.java:101) ~[minecraft-clientOnly-8cf9c5407c-1.20.5-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_20_5.1.20.5+build.1-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.screen.Screen.wrapScreenError(Screen.java:467) ~[minecraft-clientOnly-8cf9c5407c-1.20.5-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_20_5.1.20.5+build.1-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Mouse.onMouseButton(Mouse.java:101) ~[minecraft-clientOnly-8cf9c5407c-1.20.5-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_20_5.1.20.5+build.1-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Mouse.method_22686(Mouse.java:186) ~[minecraft-clientOnly-8cf9c5407c-1.20.5-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_20_5.1.20.5+build.1-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.util.thread.ThreadExecutor.execute(ThreadExecutor.java:108) ~[minecraft-common-8cf9c5407c-1.20.5-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_20_5.1.20.5+build.1-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Mouse.method_22684(Mouse.java:186) ~[minecraft-clientOnly-8cf9c5407c-1.20.5-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_20_5.1.20.5+build.1-v2.jar:?]
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWMouseButtonCallbackI.callback(GLFWMouseButtonCallbackI.java:43) [lwjgl-glfw-3.3.3.jar:?]
    at org.lwjgl.system.JNI.invokeV(Native Method) ~[lwjgl-3.3.3.jar:?]
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwWaitEventsTimeout(GLFW.java:3509) [lwjgl-glfw-3.3.3.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.blaze3d.systems.RenderSystem.limitDisplayFPS(RenderSystem.java:236) [minecraft-clientOnly-8cf9c5407c-1.20.5-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_20_5.1.20.5+build.1-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.MinecraftClient.render(MinecraftClient.java:1345) [minecraft-clientOnly-8cf9c5407c-1.20.5-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_20_5.1.20.5+build.1-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.MinecraftClient.run(MinecraftClient.java:888) [minecraft-clientOnly-8cf9c5407c-1.20.5-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_20_5.1.20.5+build.1-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:265) [minecraft-clientOnly-8cf9c5407c-1.20.5-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_20_5.1.20.5+build.1-v2.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.game.minecraft.MinecraftGameProvider.launch(MinecraftGameProvider.java:470) [fabric-loader-0.15.10.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.Knot.launch(Knot.java:74) [fabric-loader-0.15.10.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClient.main(KnotClient.java:23) [fabric-loader-0.15.10.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.devlaunchinjector.Main.main(Main.java:86) [dev-launch-injector-0.2.1+build.8.jar:?]

My recipe is defined like this:
{
  "type": "minecraft:crafting_shaped",
  "pattern": [
    "/  ",
    "   ",
    "PDP"
  ],
  "key": {
    "/": {
      "item": "minecraft:stick"
    },
    "P": {
      "tag": "minecraft:planks"
    },
    "D": {
      "item": "minecraft:diamond"
    }
  },
  "result": {
    "item": "ingamesoundboard:uwu_sound"
  }
}

I tried looking around to see if anyone else had this problem and couldn't find anything. I also checked that I was using the right item name and recipe format.

Are you sure the item ingamesoundboard:uwu_sound well exists ?

I had the exact same problem. Try changing "item" in "result" from "item" to:
"result": {
    "id": "ingamesoundboard:uwu_sound"
  }

This worked for me and hope it helps your case!
